# Getting Error "{"errorMessages":["There was an error parsing JSON. Check that your request body is valid."]}

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

`curl --request POST \ --url 'https://bankofloyal.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue' \ --user user_email:$JIRA_TOKEN \ --header 'Accept: application/json' \ --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \ --data '{ "fields": { "project": { "key": "'$JIRA_PROJECT'" }, "parent": { "key": "'$PARENT_ISSUE_KEY'" }, "components": [ { "id": "'$COMPONENT_ID'" } ], "summary": "Directories with migration changes: '"${DIR_JOINED}"'", "description": "Name of models: '"${MODEL_NAMES}"'", "issuetype": { "name": "Sub-task" } } }'`

I wanted a ticket to be generated using the cURL but getting JSON Parse error. While debugging I found the problem is in summary and description of the body, wrongly using the variable DIR_CHANGED and MODEL_NAME, can u suggest me some other ways. i have already tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70208161/how-to-use-variables-inside-data-raw-json-string-in-a-curl-command#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20use,quotes%20to%20enclose%20the%20variables.)

Comment: The above JSON indeed has syntax error. See https://jqplay.org/s/aHBbLDuLss8. Escaping the inner double quotes fixed this. See https://jqplay.org/s/cvxjrEAsZix.

Comment: Observe the escaped double quotes in `summary` and `description` fields.

Comment: This as well is working fine https://jqplay.org/s/hBYQLwWqDh6 but giving error in github actions

Comment: With https://jqplay.org/s/hBYQLwWqDh6, what is the error that you're getting now?